# Ionic desgin --> button / slide item background-color and round button / sqaure avatar questions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some problems with the desgin of an ionic app page.
My App page should look like this:
[image]

but I'm unable to get the color of the sliding bar buttons changed.
The actual state of the page:

[image]

Furhtermore, I don't know how to make such an "circle" button.
I know, that I could use the < ion-fab > button option, but then I'm unable to format it the way I want to. (the button above the label and the item-slider, but it's allways in front of the other items if I use < ion-fab > )

And my last question would be, if there is a < ion-avatar > option, or a similar approach to the < ion-avatar > option, that doesn't cut of edges off of my pictures.

My actual html part:

```
 <ion-content>
    <img class="img-head" src="assets/img/header_daten_dokumente.jpg">
    <hr>
    <ion-searchbar no lines (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="{{'Suche nach Dokumenten'|translate}}">
    </ion-searchbar>
    <div class="center">
        <button ion-button round color="hnwGruen1" (click)="addDocument()">
          <ion-icon name="add" large></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-label class="hnw-label" >{{"Daten/Dokumente hinzufügen"|translate}}</ion-label>
      
      <!--        -->
    </div>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let document of myData.documentsData">
      <button ion-item color="black" (click)="editDocument(document)">
          <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="assets/img/Icon_dokumente.svg">
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-avatar item-right>
            <img src="assets/img/icon-aerzte.svg">
          </ion-avatar>
          <h3 ion-text>{{document.doc.xName}}</h3>
          <p ion-text *ngIf="document.doc.arzt!=''">{{document.doc.arzt}}</p>
          
      </button>
        <ion-item-options  side="left">
          <button ion-button color="hnwGruen1">
              <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
              {{"Versenden"|translate}}
            </button>
          <button ion-button color="hnwGruen2" (click)="editDocument(document.doc)">
              <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
              {{"Editieren"|translate}}
            </button>
          <button ion-button color="hnwGruen3" (click)="deleteDocument(document.doc._id)">
              <ion-icon name="cut"></ion-icon>
              {{"Löschen"|translate}}
            </button>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-content>
```

The functionality was pretty easy to implement, compared to the design ;-(

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by ms self.

```
<ion-list class="ion-list">
    <ion-item-sliding  *ngFor="let item of myData.arztData">
      <ion-item class="ion-item1" tappable (click)="openArzt(item.doc)"  style="background-color: oldlace">
        <ion-row >
          <img class="img-left" src="assets/img/Icon_dokumente.svg">
          <p class="output">{{item.doc.xName}} <br> {{item.doc.fachrichtung}}<br> {{item.doc.tel}} <br>
          </p>
           <img class="img-right" src="assets/icon/auswahl_button.svg">
        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="left">
         <button ion-button color="hnwGruen2" (click)="openArzt(item.doc)">
            <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
            {{"Editieren"|translate}}
          </button>
         <button ion-button color="hnwGruen3" (click)="deleteArzt(item.doc._id)">
            <ion-icon name="cut"></ion-icon>
            {{"Löschen"|translate}}
          </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

and:

```
.ion-list{
    margin-left: -30px!important;
}
.ion-item1{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px!important;
}
.img-left{
    margin-left: 0px!important;
    margin-right: 10px!important;
    width: 10% !important;
    height:30px !important;
}
.img-right{
    margin-left: 0px!important;
    margin-right: 0px!important;
    width: 5% !important;
    height:30px !important;
    text-align: right;
} 
.output{
    margin-left: 30px!important;
    width: 70% !important;
}
```

Made it for me. I still don't know if that is the right apporach, but what ever. For now it works ;-)